# Replace Integer with 100% in string java

Tags: java, regex

I'm getting a String from an rss feed. I wanna change the width from the rss feed to 100%. I am getting it as a string. eg change width="393" to width=100%.

I tried this but it didnt work.

```
String s = newslist.getDescription();
String f=s.replace("width =\".*?\"", "width =\"\"");
```

But string f is not any different to s.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Also extra space before =. Try http://www.regexr.com/ for testing regexes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using regular expressions in a function that doesn't interpret it. Instead, use [`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-):

```
String f=s.replaceAll("width =\".*?\"", "width =\"\"");
```